# Workaround for :Q to :q while quitting in VIM

Tags: vimrc

When typing fast, sometimes the `:q` is taken as `:Q` and it is annoying when you have to repeat that for twice or thrice before actually quitting the Vim session.

Is there a way to make `:Q` to `:q` to overcome the above said problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of mapping or abbreviating, I would use a custom command to actually create a new behavior for this edge-case:

```
 command! Q :q
```

Now you can use `:Q` to have the same effect as `:q`, without any risk of overriding any function name/other mapping.

You can then define other command depending on your usage, adding a `!`, using `W` ...

---

Also worth knowing, as a workaround, to map `;` to `:` and `:` to `;`. This make the command line accessible without having to press the `shift` key, thus preventing the `:Q` to arise.

```
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : ;
```

Comment: The map `;` to `:` may create some confusion if you have your muscle memory tuned to the `shift` `+` `:`

Comment: Of course, I wouldn't recommand it either, but some people do use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHm36-na4-4

Answer (score -3):

You can use command abbreviation for it.

```
 :cabbr Q q
```

Put this in ~/.vimrc file.

Whenever you type :Q, it will be automatically converted to :q and file will be exited.
Similarly, you can use abbreviations like

```
 :cabbr W! w!
 :cabbr wQ wq
```

as well.

Comment: Edit : same works for :W to :w but my airline appearance changes when I do :W instead of :w

Comment: For someone who might want to work with Qt more, that can pose a problem.

Comment: If you have function names starting with W or Q also, it shouldn't be a problem. Our abbreviation works only when you type a space or a enter after W or Q. For function starting with Q or W, the next character will be a alphabet and not a space. So, it won't be a problem.

Comment: _If you have function names starting with W or Q also, it shouldn't be a problem._ - Really?  [These guys](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_builtin_command_using_cabbrev) must be thoroughly confused then. :)

Comment: In my case, it isnt a problem. I have used abbr, not map. Abbreviation expands only when we type a space or enter. I don't have one letter function. So, it isnt a problem. If I would have used cmap for it, every time when I type W or Q, it would have immediately changed to q or w.

Comment: Try this: `:cabbr Q q`, then `:r Q`.  Then again, I suppose you'll tell me this isn't a problem either, because you're working on Windows, where filenames are case-insensitive. :)

Comment: Yes, it would be a problem if we have a single letter file. I name a file with more than four characters.

Comment: You still don't get it, do you.  It's a problem whenever you need to type `Q` anywhere else than at the beginning of the line.  Try this: `:cabbr Q q`, then `:ZQ`.  But... you don't use commands ending with Q. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39994/discussion-between-sibicoder-and-sato-katsura).